# Trying to create a Makefile file for an assembly/nasm application

Tags: assembly, makefile, compilation, nasm

I'm trying to create a simple make file, the commands I'm using now are:

```
$ nasm -f elf64 main.asm
$ ld -s -o test1 main.o
```

That's it. How can I create a Makefile from them? I've read the manuals but I haven't gotten any close to the solution.

Comment: Surely you must have tried something, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @user657267, surely you've read my question, what's not clear in it?

Comment: You haven't explained what your exact problem with make is, other than "I don't know how to write a makefile", which [isn't a good format for SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason).

Comment: @user657267, right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could build one, using the simplest rule:

```
<target>: <source>
       <build command>
```

your makefile would look like this:

```
all: test1

main.o:  main.asm
        nasm -f elf64 main.asm

test1:   main.o
        ld -s -o test1 main.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more generic makefile that handle various `.asm` files and make an excutable out of them

With this one you can directly include libc macros directly in your `.asm` files as long as you add the correct header to `$(HEADERS)`

With the makefile below you can use `STDIN_FILENO`, `AF_INET` and all the system calls numbers such as `__NR_write`

If you find that `cpp` can't replace a macro... maybe it's an `enum` ?
(Like `SOCK_STREAM` is for example)

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
.PHONY: print_name clean fclean re
MAKEFLAGS += --warn-undefined-variables
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules
.RECIPEPREFIX = >

SHELL := zsh
SRC_EXTENSION= asm
SRCS = $(wildcard *.$(SRC_EXTENSION)) 
TMPS = $(patsubst %.$(SRC_EXTENSION), %.tmp, $(SRCS))
OBJS = $(patsubst %.tmp, %.o, $(TMPS))
HEADERS = \
   -imacros sys/socket.h \
   -imacros sys/syscall.h \
   -imacros unistd.h \
   #end
AS  = nasm
ASFLAGS += -g -f elf64
LINKER = cc
LDFLAGS +=  -static -nostdlib -mno-red-zone
NAME =  main 

all:  $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
> $(LINKER) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@ 

%.o:  %.tmp
> ${AS} ${ASFLAGS} -o $@ $^

.SECONDARY: $(wildcard *.tmp)

%.tmp:  %.asm
> cpp -w -P $(HEADERS) $^ | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$$/d' > $@ 

print_name:
> @echo $(NAME)

clean:
> rm -rf *.o(N) *.tmp(N)

fclean:  clean
> rm -f ${NAME}

re:   fclean all
```

Comment: Note that the standard file extension most people use for NASM source files is `.asm`.  NASM and make of course don't care, but if you use any software that has convenient defaults based on filename you might prefer `.asm`.  (e.g. editors for syntax-highlighting and editing modes like emacs's asm mode, or GUI desktop stuff.)

Comment: Oh, I guess you're using `.nasm` for NASM + C-preprocessor source files.  Interesting.  That's common with GAS source files (gcc does it automatically for `.S`, unlike `.s`), but for NASM people usually convert CPP macro definitions from `asm/unistd_64.h` or whatever to NASM `%define` macros, instead of actually using CPP on NASM source.  But this was works too, and avoids needing to make NASM versions of C headers that contain only `#define`, no prototypes or declarations.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't know about the extension thing, thanks. The reason I am using that extension is I  just followed a tutorial.
IIUC you are saying the common solution is to generate `nasm` macro files (with a bunch of `%defines`) that you `%include` in your `.nasm` source files, correct ?
I have thought about doing that but it seemed a bit more complex and `%include` seems to be a foot gun. Good to know thanks.
On the other hand now you have to deal with complexity elsewhere : Find where macros are defined and have `cpp` follow the `#includes`... Not that easy actually

Comment: yeah, one trick is to write a `.c` or something that includes the headers that define the constants you want (according to the man page for using the system calls or functions you want), like `MAP_PRIVATE` and `O_RDONLY` or whatever.  Then compile it with `gcc -dM` to dump just the macro definitions, omitting the prototypes and other C stuff.  `sed` or other text processing tools can turn `#define foo 123` into `%define foo 123` very easily, and NASM expression syntax is similar enough to CPP that definitions like `%define foo (bar)|(baz)` still just work.

Comment: [Looking for mmap flag values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38602525) shows an example.  Also [Opening file modes in x86 assembly Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71558966) .  (I think other people have posted answers with similar methods, too, but my search terms including "-dM" just found my own answers.)

Comment: I forgot about one issue with just using `-dM` : some constants are specified in octal, like `O_CREAT` being `0100`.  In NASM, that's the same as `100` (decimal), unlike in C and GAS where it's octal.  (NASM `0q100`).

Comment: @PeterCordes Ha, I knew there would a footgun somewhere :)
I found that my solution works pretty well actually. I had an issue with SOCK_STREAM... Turns out it was an `enum` ! Not all ALL CAPS names are macros