# Opening file modes in x86 assembly Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm learning x86 assembly Linux from the book "Programming from the Ground up", and currently I'm learning how to open a file and read from or write to it.
I'm having trouble with the options for opening files. I know 0 is for read-only, 03101 is for write and truncate, but where can I get the full documentation to all the open options?

Comment: In the C include files. On my system they are in _/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl-linux.h_

Comment: I looked at it and I didn't see anything that's related to the file opening options, am I missing something here ?

Comment: May be different on your system. Mine has e.g. `#define O_WRONLY 01` and `# define O_TRUNC 01000`

Comment: May be it's because i'm using WSL interesting,...

Comment: I've found it int /usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h thanks for the help I'll close this question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about WSL, it's about what Linux distro you chose to install in your WSL. ​Different distros will put things in different places in the filesystem.
​ `locate  '*fcntl*.h'` is a good way to find the appropriate headers.

You can always compile a C program that includes the documented headers (which will pull in the "real" headers), and look at its `gcc -E -dM` macro defines.  Or even

```
gcc -E -dM /usr/include/fcntl.h | grep ' O_'
```

to filter just the O_ macro constants.  (That `fcntl.h` is I think likely to be in the plain /usr/include, not buried somewhere, but maybe that's just my Arch GNU/Linux distro keeping it simple.  It keeps Linux-specific libc headers like `<asm/unistd.h>` in `/usr/include/asm/`, where you can find `unistd_32.h` and `unistd_64.h` for 32 and 64-bit call numbers, respectively.)  Or let the usual include-path search happen:

```
echo '#include <fcntl.h>' | gcc -E -dM - | grep ' O_'
```

**For NASM, beware that some of these constants are written in octal, such as `#define O_CREAT 00000100` in `asm-generic/fcntl.h`**.  Unlike C and the GNU assembler, in NASM `0100` is the same as decimal `100` (`0x64` not `0x40`).  [In NASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564402/how-to-represent-octal-numbers-in-assembly), you want `0q100`, or equivalently `100o`.

So if you just turn the CPP `#define` text into `%define` or `equ` with `sed` or something, the same text will have a different value when interpreted as a numeric literal by NASM instead of C or GAS.

---

Or write code that does `printf("%x, %x\n", O_CREAT, O_TRUNC)` or whatever to print out some constants you're interested in, whatever header they came from.  (Or print out their bitwise OR, like `O_CREAT|O_TRUNC`).

The permission mode bit constants like `S_IRUSR` are defined in terms of other constants like `__S_IREAD` so it's a bit of a rats nest to follow; probably just printing it out is a good idea.  Or simply write permission bits in octal, like `mov edx, 0o666` (NASM) or `mov $0666, %edx` (GAS).  (Letting umask clear the write-for-other bit on file creation).

---

The names of the constants to look for can be found in the man page, [`open(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).

---

See also [Looking for mmap flag values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602525/looking-for-mmap-flag-values) for another version of this answer, for those constants.

*[Trying to create a Makefile file for an assembly/nasm application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582462/trying-to-create-a-makefile-file-for-an-assembly-nasm-application/77197633#77197633)* suggests `-imacros` to include some specific header files only for their macro definitions, which I guess is an alternative to using `-dM` to prepare a separate file of macro defs.

Beware that some constants are defined as `enum` not macros.

Answer (score 0):

Using: Windows Subsystem
I have found the correct file for x86 asm linux in /usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h