# Including C headers from assembly

Tags: assembly, header, c-preprocessor, att, gnu-assembler

I've been writing assembly on linux for a while and I often find myself in need of including C headers which contain macro, enum and struct definitions (but clearly I just care about the macros). So, what I usually do is writing something like:

```
.if 0
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
...
.endif
```

Doing this I have no problem and the code compiles correctly.

Is there a more elegant way?

P.S. I wouldn't like to use cc -dM on those headers before including them

Comment: I've stood before the same problem years ago and didn't find a better solution either.

Comment: That `.if 0` trick is actually a pretty good workaround if you need to include headers that mix C with macros.  (Some headers like `asm/unistd.h` are purely macros and can be included without problems.)

Comment: @PeterCordes. Yeh, I know about ```asm/...``` headers, but some of them are pretty bastard.  Try including ```asm/fcntl.h```. In my case there are even some struct definitions (don't know why).

Comment: Also related: [Opening file modes in x86 assembly Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71558966)